# Meaning of down vote for down voting question

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

Please see this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79568/how-to-plot-x2y2-12y2z2-12x2z2-12-0-in-3d).

I down-voted this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79570/1997) as given the question title and the first line I sincerely believe the answer provided was not correct.

I provided my rationale in an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79583/1997).

I note this led to a penalty:
[image]

I am trying to understand the reason either I can correct my error in understanding, misconception or behavioural breach or other misunderstanding.

Comment: I fully accept that the answer I down-voted was instructive in use of `ContourPlot3D` and I note has received 2 further up-votes. I also note a comment to the answer consistent with my answer, viz. f=0. I will leave my answer but remain uncertain what my error is.

Comment: One point is subtracted from your rep each time you downvote an answer. That is so mainly to discourage "downvoting wars" among users.

Comment: Anyway, I suggest posting a comment explaining the reasons on the answers you downvote, as courtesy.

Comment: @belisarius thank you for this clarification...I guess I thought my answer was the explanation but not a direct comment...now I have learned policy and will improve my manners

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [Why do you lose reputation for down-voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15863/158428)

(I am posting as an answer so that this appears answered.)

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance.